# How to merge two arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am really confused about merging two arrays, if this is really called merging or recursive mode. I have seen some examples before, but I didn't really understand how to get the results i needed.

```
$arrays = array('A1','A2','A3'); 
$result = array('B1','B2','B3');
```

I wanted to get something like A1 B1, A1 B2, A1 B3. Then A2 B1, A2 B2, A2 B3, then A3 B1, A3 B2, A3 B3, but i don't really seem to understand how this is supposed to be done.
I found this code online

```
function get_combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_key => $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = $result_item + array($property_key => $property_value);
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I tried changing some values in it, but it didn't work for me, because i don't know how to make something like this in the example. Please forgive me if there is a duplicate somewhere, I just don't know how to make it work. Any help will be appreciated.

**Answer:**
Ok guys, thanks to you all, I was really able to make it work. I wasn't able to Answer it in a normal way due to some limitations in my account. Thanks to chris85 for his example. It works great. I was able to store these values into an array. This is my code:

```
$arrays = array('A1','A2','A3'); 
$result = array('B1','B2','B3');
$myarray = array();

    foreach($arrays as $value) {
    foreach($result as $value2){
    $myarray[] = $value . $value2;
         }
    }
        print_r ($myarray);
```

Comment: Do you want output like this as string? Like this "A1, B1, B2, B3, A2, B1, B2 B3, A3, B1, B2, B3"

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Very sorry. I want an output like this A1 B1, A1 B2, A1 B3. Then A2 B1, A2 B2, A2 B3, then A3 B1, A3 B2, A3 B3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$array1 = array('A1','A2','A3'); 
$array2 = array('B1','B2','B3');
foreach($array1 as $val1) {
    foreach($array2 as $val2)echo $val1.$val2. " "; 
    echo "\n";
}

Output:

A1B1 A1B2 A1B3 
A2B1 A2B2 A2B3 
A3B1 A3B2 A3B3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your purpose is not suitable for 1-dimensional array. You must use pairs or 2-dimensional array as result. Your desired operation is really Cartesian product.

```
$arrays = array('A1','A2','A3'); 
$result = array('B1','B2','B3');
$i=0;
foreach($arrays as $value1)
  foreach($result as $value2)
    {
    $final[$i][1]=$value1;
    $final[$i][2]=$value2;
    $i++;
    }
```